# Bootstrap modal background gets darker on button click

Tags: c#, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7 in my project and I'm using the bootstrap modal. I've been having issues recently with the modal's background. The modal opens up on a button click. If I reopen the modal, without clicking on the submit button, the modal background gets darker for every single button click, rendering the background with no transparency after 3 or 4 clicks.

Here are the screenshots:[On 1st button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1eZ8.png)

[2nd time button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GITyi.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap multiple modals modal-backdrop issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588698/bootstrap-multiple-modals-modal-backdrop-issue)